# search checklistbox on textbox but don't remember checked items c# c sharp

Tags: c#, search, textbox, checklistbox

When I checked items on list in checkedListBox1 and search some items using textBox1 my previous check is gone. When i search using textBox1 and check some item on list and search another item previous checked is gone too. Any solutions? C#

```
void ladujZBazy(string mustContains)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
        listSurowceTabela.Clear();
        indexes.Clear();

        bazaproduktowDBEntities dc = new bazaproduktowDBEntities();

        var c1 = from d in dc.SurowceTabela select d.NazwaSurowca;
        var c2 = from d in dc.SurowceTabela select "(" + d.PartiaSurowca + ")";
        var c3 = from d in dc.SurowceTabela select d.IloscSurowca;
        var c4 = from d in dc.SurowceTabela select d.JednostkaSurowca;

        listSurowceTabela.Add(c1.ToList());
        listSurowceTabela.Add(c2.ToList());
        listSurowceTabela.Add(c3.ToList());
        listSurowceTabela.Add(c4.ToList());

        for (int i = 0; i < listSurowceTabela[0].Count; i++)
        {
            string strToAdd = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < listSurowceTabela.Count; j++)
            {
                strToAdd += " " + listSurowceTabela[j][i] + " ";
            }
            if (mustContains == null)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(strToAdd);
                indexes.Add(i);
            }
            else if (strToAdd.ToLower().Contains(mustContains.ToLower()))
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(strToAdd);
                indexes.Add(i);
            }

        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ladujZBazy(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: the searches are being removed because the function `ladujZBazy()` is clearing them. you can pass a 2nd parameter to your function(*`bool` type*) which will by default be `false` until supplied by the caller(*in your case textbox's textchanged event*) and wrap you checkboxlist clearing code inside if the parameter is `true`.

Comment: thanks for advice but i try and still checked items is gone. Please write some code with bool type to this.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the Clear() methods at the top of your code. This should demonstrate that you are clearing those values. Then work your way through what actually needs to be cleared and what does not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem basically resides at these lines in `ladujZBazy()`:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
indexes.Clear();
```

where you are calling to clear all the contents of the `checkedListBox1` and it's stored indexes.

So, every call made to your function, you are clearing up all the contents from the `checkedListBox1` and then *recreating/appending* contents back to it. Hence, it is just refreshing all the items in the `checkedListBox1`(*i.e. removing any already checked items in the list.*).

So, we have 2 ways by which we can make it work.

1. We can add a `Boolean` parameter to the `ladujZBazy()` which will determine whether to *clear* the `checkedListBox1` or not.

And your modified `ladujZBazy()` will then look something like this:

```
void ladujZBazy(string mustContains, bool dropIndexes)
{
    // the below code will only run the value is supplied as TRUE
    if(dropIndexes)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
        listSurowceTabela.Clear();
        indexes.Clear();
    }        

    // your rest of the code goes here
}
```

And then call it from your textbox's `TextChanged` event as:

```
ladujZBazy(textBox1.Text,false);// pass TRUE to clear the checked items
```

2. Or we can move the index and checked item *Clearing and CheckListBox Refreshing Logic* to a separate function as:

   ```
   private void refreshChkListBox()
   {
      checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
      listSurowceTabela.Clear();
      indexes.Clear();
      //your code to append items to list goes here
   }
   ```

And later call this function to refresh the `CheckListBox` if you have a need for it.